# how would I detect if "multiple" attribute is supported for file input elements?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, modernizr

Internet Explorer does not support the `multiple` attribute for `<input type="file" />`. However, its not only IE that lacks this support... also certain mobile browsers do not support the `multiple` attribute. So simply detecting that the browser is IE is not the ideal solution.

So how would I detect if the `multiple` attribute is supported for for `<input type="file" />` with JavaScript?

### UPDATE

It seems like Modernizr has support for new HTML5 input element attributes:

http://modernizr.com/docs/#input

The accepted solution seems to work, however, since I'm already using Modernizr, my solution is the following:

```
/**
 * Determines if the given attribute is supported for <input /> elements.
 * 
 * @param attribute - the attribute to test for (ex. "multiple")
 */
function isInputAttributeSupported(attribute) {
    return (Modernizr.input[attribute]) ? true : false;
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var inp = document.createElement("input");
inp.setAttribute("multiple", "true");
var supportsMultiple = inp.multiple===true;
```

Comment: I don't think `setAttribute` is not supported in all browsers

Comment: I might be wrong... but I thought old versions of IE were shaky on `setAttribute` support?

Comment: And they do not support multiple so it does not matter.

Comment: @Hristo It appears it's just [shaky with certain attributes](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t1110) (mainly `style`), but the method is still available.

Comment: You might want to add the deletion of the element after this test, no reason to leave it hanging around.

Comment: @MgSam It wasn't added to the DOM. It will just be garbage collected when the function scope exits.

Answer (score 15):

You can try checking for the existence of the corresponding property:

```
var supportsMultipleFiles = 'multiple' in document.createElement('input');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbZvS/

Comment: At first i thought that the code in your post is not working in IE, but I tested it now, and it works. But when I copy paste the code from your post, it puts invisible characters into the code. I noticed them in Chrome in developer tools in Sources tab: `var supportsMultipleFiles = 'multiple' in â€‹document.â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹createElement('input');`