# Detect Support for Multiple Files

Tags: html

Is there a way to detect if the html5 feature for multiple files selection/upload is supported in a particular browser?

```
<input type="file multiple>
```

I guess i can detect the browser and display the not supported message if it is IE9 or below, but i think feature detection will be a better practice.

Any thoght?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457770/how-would-i-detect-if-multiple-attribute-is-supported-for-file-input-elements

Comment: what...i google and stackoverflow this issue and i didn't find anything. thanks thou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [how would I detect if "multiple" attribute is supported for file input elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457770/how-would-i-detect-if-multiple-attribute-is-supported-for-file-input-elements][1])

Possible duplicate answer to your question.

Summary is (other answer)

```
var inp = document.createElement("input");
inp.setAttribute("multiple", "true");
var supportsMultiple = inp.multiple===true;
```