# Upload form works/doesn't work depend on?

Tags: html, forms, firefox, user-agent

I have unusual occurence.

I have form like this:

```
  <input type="file" name="public[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

In my computer (win7, firefox) it works fine, I can upload muliple images by pressing ctrl and select photos.
My customer told me that He can select only one photo. He has win7  and winXP.
Does it depend on browser?

I have Mozilla/5.0

[image: user agent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a browser version issue, not all will support the multiple tag. [Here is another post talking about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852298/testing-if-a-browser-supports-multiple-file-uploads)